# Отображение содержимого input.value в режиме реального времени в .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

При вводе данных в input они должны сразу же отображаться в .innerHTML. Как это сделать?

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var here = document.getElementById('here');



var par = document.createElement('p');
par.innerHTML = parseInt(one.value);
here.appendChild(par);
```

```css
#here {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one">
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С помощью обработчика события `input`

```js
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('here').innerText = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one">
<div id="here"></div>
```